# Can any one help me with these Database query

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, simplecursoradapter, android-cursor

I wanted to get the result of this Cursor Database query in String or int values but couldn't. I know about coursor.getstring or getint but i am having probelm applying in the below case and query function. Below is the function with query.. I made my database java activity and this method was in it...

```
public Cursor getUpdatedAmount(){
String amountQuery="select sum(amount) from travelling_exp where call_id=1;";
Cursor cursor = myDatabase.rawquery(amountQuery,null);
return cursor;
}
```

The Query is Working fine without any error.
Basically i wanted the sum of amount column after deletion or changes to my database, save and show the sum value in a edittext. But the problem is i cannot convert cursor value to a value string or int.

this is how i implemented the above DB Query function in my other java file until now :

```
Cursor cursor = myDB.getUpdatedAmount();
```

The fucntion returns the sum amount for ex if values in amount column is 1000,2000,3000 then the above query will return the sum = 6000. so i want to save and show that 6000 in an ediitext. 
I tried using .toString  and finding other methods to work but no luck.
Can anybody help me with this one. Its quite important for me and my project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show what you have tried, and the errors your got.

Comment: i tried cursor.tostring; but it gave me some value which i was not able to understand like android.view......2131@ds .. something like this ..and

i tried converting cursor to string using String abc = String.format();

but was not successfull..
My query is fine i am getting the value when i run the query in sqlite but i want to convert to returned cursor value in string or int so that i can show in a ediitext.

Comment: yeah toString is not what you want. you need to either use `getInt` or `getString` probably something like `getInt(0)`

Comment: i see. i want to give u an example then maybe u can understand my probelm..In my table there is a column by the name "amount" saving different amount of purchases i made. i delete and update my table so i wanted to have the sum of amount to show the total amount left after deletion  insertion and updation operation.. so i made this function..
this funtion returns the sum amount left in the amount column BUT in cursor value which is not possible to set in an edittext.
so i wanted any conversion method or some other method so as to convert this cursor value to string or int .

Comment: yeah i completely understood your question... and what I said still applies...

Comment: i understand getint(0) or gestring(1). I used that in fetching the data wth cursor.movetonext cursor.startfromfirst() methods..but how do i get the value in string? like if do cursor.movetofirst() then which value will it get in the amount column ?? first field one or sum ?? i am kind of confused with the query i made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really not that difficult, if you would test out `getInt(0)` you'd see that you've got your answer, but here it is

Since you're selecting only the SUM then only 1 column and 1 row will be returned, that's why `getInt(0)` works.

```
public String getUpdatedAmount(){
    String amountQuery="select sum(amount) from travelling_exp where call_id=1;";
    Cursor cursor = myDatabase.rawquery(amountQuery,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        return "" + cursor.getInt(0);
    }
}
```

Notice: I've changed your function to return a `String` and not a `Cursor`

So you can use it like this:

```
txtTotal.setText(getUpdatedAmount());
```

Comment: Actually this is what i was confused about , how to apply getint or getstring and the cursor to avoid conversion problem .. I will surely try this.. Thank you so much for a speedy reply and help..:)

Comment: Well i applied it now. First it gave me an error with getInt(0).toString() line "Cannot invoke toString() on primitive type int. I changed getint to getString and then error to add return statement occured because maybe the retunr cursor.getint(0).tostring(); is in further brackets.... so should it be "return string" return amountquery ?? can u help me with this ?

Comment: I should've known better than that! I'm mobile right now but a quick fix would be `return ""+cursor.getInt(0)`

Comment: Error : The Method(getUpdatedAmount) Must Return a return type of String.

Comment: After the if return a string that justs says error or something. The if is to make sure that the query actually worked

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Everything works.. Thank you very much... Sorry it took so long for marking your answer as the right one..